# Iterating over arraylist of arraylist using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, arraylist

I am having a Json arraylist which contains another arraylist. I need to iterate over both these arraylists and display records in table.

This is what i have tried so far.

I tried using two ng-repeats in same tr.But it didnt work

```
    <tr class="ng-scope"
    ng-repeat="msgcounts in pastdata"  ng-repeat="past in msgcounts.arrayList_Jsons"  >


    <td class="numeric">{{ 1}}</td>
    <td class="numeric">{{ past.aggregator}}</td>
    <td class="numeric">{{past.loadedCount}}</td>
    <td class="numeric">{{past.sentCount}}</td>
    <td>{{past.sentCount}}</td>
    <td >{{past.failedCount}}</td>
    <td class="numeric">{{past.replyCount}}</td>                                                                                                       <td class="numeric">{{msgcounts.date}}</td>

</tr>
```

I tried creating a div in tr tag

```
<tr class="ng-scope"
        ng-repeat="msgcounts in pastdata">
        <div   ng-repeat="past in msgcounts.arrayList_Jsons"  >             

        <td class="numeric">{{ 1}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{ past.aggregator}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.loadedCount}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.sentCount}}</td>
        <td>{{past.sentCount}}</td>
        <td >{{past.failedCount}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.replyCount}}</td>                                                                        

</div>

       <td class="numeric">{{msgcounts.date}}</td>
<tr>
```

Here is the sample data:

```
{
[
{date1,[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}]},
{date2,[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}]},
{date3,[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}]},
]
}
```

Please suggest me what can be done in this case.

Html should look like this
[image: This is sample html format]

Comment: Can you paste what your data looks like?

Comment: first arraylist contains jsonarraylist and one date. second arraylist is of Json with long values in it @MathewBerg

Comment: Does "arraylist" mean "array"?

Comment: no its an arraylist of Json that have  long values in it  @thomas

Comment: So what is supposed to happen? What does each element of `pastdata` represent in the View? Is each one a table, a set of rows?

Comment: Please wait i will edit the question to add sample data @NewDev

Comment: Please check the edited question @MathewBerg

Comment: @kirti, that's useful, but my question is ultimately about how each `{date1,[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2}]}` is mapped to HTML. What does it represent?

Comment: This is a report data which represents various counts of database values on each date @NewDev

Comment: @kirti, perhaps I'm unable to articulate what I'm asking. What I don't understand is what you want the resulting HTML to look like

Comment: Html must be in table format. i mean it should iterate the inner arraylist in the first seven columns and show date according to first arraylist. I know its confusing but thats how it has to be done @NewDev

Comment: @kirti... honestly, I'm ready to give up... pls show - by editing the question - exactly and accurately what the resulting `<table>` looks like and where each data resides. Otherwise, we'll go around in circles and waste time by giving you best-guess answers, like the one below

Comment: let me do that @NewDev

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/z7M3LmlSaa6mZREi3Fhm?p=preview

Comment: Please check the edited question @NewDev

Comment: @kirti, sorry, this gives us next nothing. It's not clear how the data - the inner and outer arrays - map to this table. What generates a row? Is it the outer array or the inner array? What generates a column? To be useful, your "sample data" should correspond to the table you put there

Comment: how your simple data represent *aggregator, loadedCount, sentCount ...* properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't set two `ng-repeats` on one element,

and a `div` cannot be a direct child of a `tr`.

you could maybe use another `tbody` tag to solve this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="msgcounts in pastdata">
    <tr ng-repeat="past in msgcounts.arrayList_Jsons">
        <td class="numeric">{{1}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{ past.aggregator}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.loadedCount}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.sentCount}}</td>
        <td>{{past.sentCount}}</td>
        <td>{{past.failedCount}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{past.replyCount}}</td>
        <td class="numeric">{{msgcounts.date}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @kirti dose this answer you?

Comment: Nice trick but it repeats each msgcount many times causing repetition of data

Comment: well wasent that what you wanted to do?

Comment: how is the final DOM supposed to look like?

Comment: Your ans is generating tbody too many times and thus its causing all rows to be repeated many times.

Comment: @kirti, we don't understand what you expect the table to look like, and so a lot of time is wasted going back and forth

Comment: Its working for me now. I changed little bit of my code and its working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like the following :

```
$scope.groupDetails = [{
        groupingNumber: '1',

        groupDetails: [{
            sequence: '1',
            text: 'test 1',
        }]
    },
             {
        groupingNumber: '2',
               groupDetails: [{
                     sequence: '1',
                     text: 'test 2',

                 }, {sequence: '2',
                     text: 'test 3', }]
             },
           {
              groupingNumber: '3',

               groupDetails: [{
                   sequence: '3',
                   text: 'test 4',
               }]
           }
    ];
```

In the front end you can write something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="grouping in groupDetails">

    <div ng-repeat = "groupSequence in grouping.groupDetails">
            <div>{{groupSequence.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes just change the div with table tags. And format it the way you like it.

Comment: Thats what i have written in the question... Please read the question

Comment: Ok.  Tell me how the table would look like ?